# Is there Vigyan Bhairav Tantra in Hindi available online?

Tags: tantra, resource, kashmiri-shaivism

Can someone kindly provide me the pdf of Vigyan Bhairav tantra?
(I am looking for the original text and not the one written by Osho)
And yes, it should have both Sanskrit and Hindi translation.

Comment: Do you want it in Hindi or English could work?

Comment: hindi please :)

Comment: If you have another account with the same name, then merge them. You can click [contact](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/contact)  and select merge the profiles.

Comment: Okay, do you have it?

Comment: I don't have it but first register and merge your accounts. I know the link to the book for English.

Comment: i think the vigyan bhairava tantra explained by osho is the best one to read, i love it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download Vigyan Bhairav Tantra Hindi and Sanskrit by Vraj Vallabh Dvivedi eBook from [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/VijnanabhairavaWithSanskritHindiVyakhyasVrajvallabhaDwivedi/Vijnanabhairava%20With%20Sanskrit%20%26%20Hindi%20Vyakhyas%20-%20Vrajvallabha%20Dwivedi#page/n0)